# INTEGRATING x509 CERTIFICATE IN WCF ROUTING

Tags: c#, wcf, routes, certificate, x509

I wanted to create a **WCF** based application **(Nettcp)** that a client will connect to a Server and will pass thru into a **WCF Router** with a `x509 certification` security. (Sorry for the construction of sentence, because i'm a beginner in programming.)

At first, I've created a **WCF** based application **(Nettcp)** that a Client(proxy) will connect into a Server and passing thru into router **without `x509 certificate`**. (Working fine)

but when I integrated using `x509` Certificate in both side of Server and Client, it is showing up some problems.

```
Err Desc.: The client certificate is not provided. Specify a client certificate in ClientCredentials.
```

Is the message been tampered when it is passing thru **WCF Router**? How can I solve this.

here is the code in my client side, router and server:

CLIENT:

```
binding = new NetTcpBinding();
binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Message; // temporary only
binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.Certificate;
EndpointIdentity end = EndpointIdentity.CreateDnsIdentity("DOMAIN");
AddressHeader[] addressHeaders = new AddressHeader[1] { AddressHeader.CreateAddressHeader("MainSvc", string.Format("net.tcp://{0}/MainSvc", endPoint), 1) };
this.callback = new MainCallBack();
this.context = new InstanceContext(this.callback);
this.endpoint = new EndpointAddress(new Uri(string.Format("net.tcp://{0}/MainSvc", endPoint)), end, addressHeaders);
this.factory = new DuplexChannelFactory<IMain>(this.context, this.binding, this.endpoint);
this.factory.Credentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(
                    StoreLocation.LocalMachine,
                    StoreName.My,
                    X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,
                    "XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX");                this.factory.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.PeerOrChainTrust;
this.factory.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;
this.proxy = this.factory.CreateChannel();
```

SERVER:

```
mainHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Main), new Uri("net.tcp://" + ip4Address + ":35000/MainSvc"));
mainHost.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SetCertificate(
                    StoreLocation.LocalMachine,
                    StoreName.My,
                    X509FindType.FindBySerialNumber,
                    "XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX");
mainHost.Credentials.IssuedTokenAuthentication.AllowUntrustedRsaIssuers = true;
mainHost.Credentials.UserNameAuthentication.UserNamePasswordValidationMode = UserNamePasswordValidationMode.MembershipProvider;                mainHost.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.PeerOrChainTrust;
mainHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMain), tcp, "net.tcp://" + ip4Address + ":35000/MainSvc");
mainHost.Open();
Console.WriteLine("Service is running..");
```

ROUTER:

```
string mainAddress = "net.tcp://192.168.1.14:35000/MainSvc";
string backupAddress = "net.tcp://192.168.1.33:35000/MainSvc";
string routerAddress = "net.tcp://192.168.1.14:35002/AccessSvc";
NetTcpBinding routerBinding = new NetTcpBinding();
NetTcpBinding clientBinding = new NetTcpBinding();
routerBinding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Message;
routerBinding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.Certificate;
serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IDuplexSessionRouter), routerBinding, routerAddress);
ContractDescription contract = ContractDescription.GetContract(typeof(IDuplexSessionRouter));
ServiceEndpoint server = new ServiceEndpoint(contract, clientBinding, new EndpointAddress(mainAddress));
ServiceEndpoint backup = new ServiceEndpoint(contract, clientBinding, new EndpointAddress(backupAddress));
SoapProcessingBehavior spb = new SoapProcessingBehavior();
spb.ProcessMessages = false;
server.EndpointBehaviors.Add(spb);
backup.EndpointBehaviors.Add(spb);
List<ServiceEndpoint> endpointList = new List<ServiceEndpoint>();
endpointList.Add(server);
endpointList.Add(backup);
RoutingConfiguration rc = new RoutingConfiguration();
rc.FilterTable.Add(new MatchAllMessageFilter(), endpointList);
serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(new RoutingBehavior(rc));
```